# How to apply removeAtIndex for arrays of dictionary type in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have dictionary of key-value type such as:

```
var images = [String:UIImage]()
```

If it's a normal array of strings, I can have the value removed by the following:

```
images.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

But if its argument type is dictionary then I it gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type
>   'DictionaryIndex'.

How can I remove remove from such an array at a given index? Can anyone please help me on that?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered so this functionality might give back unexpected results.

Comment: I see swift has this option :removeAtIndex(index: DictionaryIndex<Key, [Value]>). But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: In this case, I believe DictionaryIndex would just be a typealias for String, the Dictionary's key type.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of that array of key-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just remove the item with its `String` key.

```
images.removeValueForKey("someString")
```

**Edit:**
Per the comments:

I don't fully understand what you mean. Im going to recreate your scenario. But I will use `Strings` instead of `UIImage's` since I'm doing this on the command line.

```
  1> var images = [String:String]() 
images: [String : String] = 0 key/value pairs
  2> images["one"] = "someting 1 2 3"
  3> images["two"] = "something else 4 5 6"
  4> images
$R0: [String : String] = 2 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = "one"
    value = "someting 1 2 3"
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "two"
    value = "something else 4 5 6"
  }
}
```

Now, based on your example, I want to remove an item.

```
  5> images.removeValueForKey("one")
$R1: String? = "someting 1 2 3"
  6> images
$R2: [String : String] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "two"
    value = "something else 4 5 6"
  }
}
```

**Edit2:**

After reading you commend and you example code a second time, I think you are misunderstanding what you have.

You have a dictionary of keys which are strings. Paired in a one to one relationship to UIImages.

So, if you remove one an item based on the key, you remove its only attribute which is an image.

Now, since you said the word array in your original question, I think this is what you want.

```
 1> var images = [String:[String]]()
```

For you, it would be `var images = String:[UIImage]

Now you have an array of images per key.

```
images: [String : [String]] = 0 key/value pairs
  1> images["one"] = [String]
  2> images["one"]!.append("first")
  3> images
$R0: [String : [String]] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "one"
    value = 1 value {
      [0] = "first"
    }
  }
}
  4> images["one"]!.append("second")
  5> images
$R1: [String : [String]] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "one"
    value = 2 values {
      [0] = "first"
      [1] = "second"
    }
  }
}
  6> images["one"]!.removeAtIndex(0)
$R2: String = "first"
  7> images
$R3: [String : [String]] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "one"
    value = 1 value {
      [0] = "second"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how we can use this option because if we use this then all values with this key are removed.

Comment: i have same problem and want to remove only one value not all for that particular key.

Comment: Yes, they would be removed. That's what you asked for. I've update my answer to demonstrate what the map looks like

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what you have. You do not have an array of images. You have just one Image per key

Comment: I made a mistake, I typed arrays, yes it is dictionary, and I want to remove the values from dictionary. Actually I have collection view which picks images from cache and images is my cache containing keys and values, if user clicks on one of the cells then that image should also be removed from cache, how can I do that?

Comment: I belive I have both scenarios in my answer. 1. Remove a single key value pair. or 2, remove a particular item based on a key and an index. Let me know if one of those isn't clear

Comment: If I have to remove a single key value pair then I need to remove it by knowing the string of it, but I didn't know how to find the String key so I stored String keys into another array and get the index at a particular array to get the String key to remove the item from the dictionary. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a Dictionary, not an Array:

```
var images = [String:UIImage]()
```

The key is type String, and there's only one value (UIImage) stored for a particular key.  If you need an array of images for each string key, you could try:

```
var images = [String: Array<UIImage>]()
```

Then to access:

```
imageList = images["someKeyString"] // returns an array of UIImages
for image in imagelist {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQvj.png)
CandyJar is a variable which created. remove command is used to remove the values as Index number/position.

```
CandyJar = {

  [0] = "Apple"

  [1] = "Mango"

  [2] = "Orange"

  [3] = "Straberry"

  [4] = "Lemon"

}
```

//remove command will removed the Lemon value as Index mention is 4.

```
 CandyJar.remove(at:4)
```

Returns:

$R6: String = "Lemon"

```
CandyJar
```

Returns:

```
$R7: [String] = 4 values {

  [0] = "Apple"

  [1] = "Mango"

  [2] = "Orange"

  [3] = "Strawberry"
```